# HackerRank Maximum Disjoint Subtree Product

Tags: algorithm, tree, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search

Can anybody give me a better explained insight about the problem Maximum Disjoint Subtree Product ([link here](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/world-codesprint-10/challenges/maximum-disjoint-subtree-product)) ?? I can't figure it out from the psetter analysis. 
I don't understand 2nd DFS approach (it tries to calculate the solution for "up subtrees"??)
Please can someone help me and/or give me other problems following the same solution approach ??? I really appreciate other problems like this one. Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a `dynamic programming` problem. Check out this [link](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/20935) before, it contains great tutorial on problems that involve `dynamic programming` on `Trees.`

Comment: Yes it is. I already saw the post you mention. But this specific problem requires a different approach. I can't find the O(N) solution that is required to solve the problem. Thanks anyway :)